# Declaring variables and functions, in what order?

Tags: javascript, performance, coding-style, readability, maintainability

#### Context

I'm learning how to code in **[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)** consistently, readably and maintainably.

I found nothing about the order of declaration of variables and functions.

#### Example:

```
var example = {

    A: function() {
        var a, b, c;
    },

    B: function() {
        var a, b, c;
    },

    C: function() {
        var a, b, c;
    }

}
```

#### Questions

- Alphabetically is the best one ?
- Is that the order can improve the speed of code execution ?

Comment: How should the order improve the execution speed? I highly doubt that, though I can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check the code quality. It can be integrated with Visual Studio and a lot of other stuff which is really nice.

JSLint suggests using something like:

```
var example = {
    A: function () {
        var a, b, c;
    },

    B: function () {
        var a, b, c;
    },

    C: function () {
        var a, b, c;
    }
};
```

Regarding the variables, it suggests declaring them always at the start of the enclosing scope, since that's actually how the code will be interpreted (that's the JavaScript semantic).

Regarding performance, you cannot improve or decrease performance by changing the order.

Regarding the order... You should do it in the order which has more sense to you (and your team). I personally like doing top-down or bottom-top (That means putting the most important functions first, and then put the dependent functions after that one, etc... or the other way around... Put the simpler functions first, and then the functions that build on top of those ones).

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is psuedo-code and not an actual ones. However, it's more a matter of code guidelines – readability, maintainability... – than other.

Also, I will consider to use [multiple var statement](http://benalman.com/news/2012/05/multiple-var-statements-javascript/) to declare variables. I use one `var` statement only if it's just declaration and the variables are logically related each other.

In addition, because [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), it also doesn't matter to JavaScript in which point of the scope you're declaring a variables: JS always move the declaration on the top, so you're free to shape the code in logical blocks that helps you to maintain and read better your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure sure what your question is but in your question `declaring variables and functions, in what order?` you mentioned the word `order` so here is something important when you declare variable and functions

```
test();
function test()
{
    alert(1);
}
```

The function called before it's declaration but it'll run and won't through any errors, but following will cause an error

```
a();
a = function()
{
    alert(1);
};
```

The function call should be called after assigning the the function expression to the variable. You can find more here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and [Decent Programming Advice](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting) and [JavaScript Hoisting Explained](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/).